# C# CUIT "Последнее действие мыши не записано"

Tags: c#, тестирование

Необходимо написать тесты интерфейса на `С#` используя `Coded UI Test`.

Так вот там есть `UIMap` который записывает действия с тестируемым приложением: запуска, нажатие на кнопки и т.д. Только почему-то в `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise` он никак не хочет записывать действие мыши и выдает странное сообщение: "Последнее действие мыши не было записано".

Хотя сами элементы он видит и проверки содержимого лейблов и других элементов выполняет.

Как это исправить? Может я что-то забыл добавить в проект?